# how do I make an image ocupy the entire grid tile

Tags: css, gridview, layout, grid

```
**[![model image][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PfBI.jpg
```

Here, is my code, I don´t know how to make them look like in the image, I tried with the templates. but it´s in vain, I don't know how to do it. I tried changing the sizes, nothing, I'm stuck
thank you for your help, btw

```
        .heromain-imgs {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 0;
        grid-template-columns: 30% % 10% 12% 12% 12% 12% 12%;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)
    }

    .picture {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .picasia {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }


    /* Picture of Asia */

    .picture img {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .picture p {
        position: absolute;
        color: red;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
    }


    /*  */

    .picsuda {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }



                 .picafrica {
        grid-column-start: 7;
        grid-column-end: 8;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3;
    }**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8GE5.jpg)

Comment: Could you give us your html code and put your project in a JSFiddle please? That would help us to understand where you're stuck.

Comment: https://github.com/bohorquez866/arbeid here is the project, and thank you so much for your help